# Rails 4 + Devise + System update the Password but Unauthorized the User and signout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

In my Rails Project, I am using Devise for authentication.

Step 1. Using email id and password - System allows to logged in.

Step 2. Tried to update the Password - Code is written HomeController rather than any devise controller.

Step 3. It allows to update the password. But by giving Unauthorized message, throws the Session & User out of the system.

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def update_password
    user = User.find(current_user.id)
    user_save = user.update_attributes(:password => params[:user][:password],
                                        :password_confirmation => params[:user][:password_confirmation])
    if user_save
        redirect_to "/MyProfile", notice: 'User data successfully saved.'
    else
        redirect_to "/MyProfile", notice: 'EROROROOROROROROR.'
    end     
  end
end
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/UpdatePassword" id="CreateUserPassword" method="post">
  <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="<%= form_authenticity_token.to_s%>">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="user[password]">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password Confirmation" name="user[password_confirmation]">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Please suggest something ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before redirect, you must sign in the user again

```
sign_in @user, :bypass => true
```

See Solution 3 under https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password

Comment: Worked ... Useful Link Thanks